# Pass a button value along with an upload file in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am quite new to javascript and for the last couple of days I am stuck and can't find a solution by myself. I have a table that drags some data from mysql and displays them in my website. The table consists of three columns ('id', Name, Surname). I have added another column consisting of buttons. The table looks like that :

[image]

The source code of the table is the following:

```
function user_clients_table_storagefolder() {

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
   if(!$con){

   die("Cannot Connect" . mysql_error());

   }
    mysql_select_db("client_app",$con);
    $get_user_clients = "SELECT `ID`,`Name`,`SurName`,`storagefolder` FROM `clients`  ";
   $clients = mysql_query($get_user_clients,$con);

   echo "<table class=table table-condensed>
   <thead>
   <tr>   
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>SurName</th>
   <th>Recipient</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>";
   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($clients)){
    echo "<action=pushnotification.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$record['ID']." </td>";
    echo "<td>".$record['Name']." </td>";
    echo "<td>".$record['SurName']." </td>";
    echo "<td>"."<button   value=".$record['Name']." id=contact>Upload File</button>"." </td>";
    echo "</tr>";

     }

echo "</table>";     
mysql_close();
```

As you can see in the source code i give a different value to each button(For example the first button has a value=Mike)

When i click on a button an uplaod form appears asking the user to upload a file:
The form looks like this :

[image]

This is been asvhieved by the following source code:

1# source code of dispalying the form:

```
<script>

$(function() {

  // contact form animations
  $('#contact').click(function() {
    $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
  })
  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#contactForm");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.fadeOut();
    }
  });

});

</script>
```

2#Source code of the form content

```
<div id="contactForm" >
                  <p><h4><font color="white"><i>First Choose the clients and then the file which will be uploaded in order to proced</i></font></h4></2>
                  <p>&nbsp;</p>
                 <input type="file" class="upload" name="onstorage" id="upload_file" size="50" name="icon" onchange="loadFile(this);" >
                  <hr>
                  <div id="myProgress">
                      <div id="myBar"></div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

The source code of the loadFile function is the following:

```
function loadFile(input) {

        //Step 1 : Defining element to show the progress
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");    
        var filetoUpload=input.files[0];

        //Step 2 : Initializing the reference of database with the filename
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`files/${filetoUpload.name}`);


        //Step 3 : Uploading file
         var task = storageRef.put(filetoUpload);

         //Step 4 : Database Storage Reference


        //Step 4 : sata_changed Event
         // state_changed events occures when file is getting uploaded 
         //(Note : when we want to show the progress what's the uploading status that time we will use this function.)
         task.on('state_changed',
            function progress(snapshot){
                var percentage = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
                //uploader.value = percentage;
                 elem.style.width = parseInt(percentage) + '%'; 
                 elem.innerHTML=parseInt(percentage)+'%';
            },
            function error(err){

            },
            function complete(){
                var downloadURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;
                // this is the url i have to store in the Database

                 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('files');

                rootRef.push({
                  url:downloadURL,
                  fullPath:(`files/${filetoUpload.name}`),
                  created: `${new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]}`
                   });



            }
        ); 
}
```

You can see that each time i choose a file i call a loadfile function and passing the input that i have uploaded. What i want to do is to pass the value of the button that i clicked along with the input. Is this possible?
Can someone please help me?

Thanks in Regards

Comment: can you include loadFile function?

Comment: my battery is 2% i hope you answered my question soon

Comment: I have included it is the source code in 1# source code of dispalying the form:

Comment: $(function() {

  // contact form animations
  $('#contact').click(function() {
    $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
  })
  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#contactForm");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.fadeOut();
    }
  });

});

Comment: i dont see loadFile , am i blind or missing something (0_0)? i will charge my battery 1st. after that ill answer

Comment: Sorry man i got a little bit confused i edited the question , i have included the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 2nd script

```
<script>
var contactName; //prepare var to save contact name/ PLACE outside document ready
$(function() { //document ready begin
// contact form animations
// $('#contact').click(function() { wrong. id is spesific. class is general. dont ever use id on multiple element. you can use class instead.
$('button[id="contact"]').click(function() {//selector to get "ALL" button with id=contact . if you use $('#contact') , only first element of id=contact can be triggered.
    contactName = $(this).val(); //set var contactName to value of the pressed button
    $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
});
...
}); //closed document ready
</script>
```

your 4th script

```
 ...
function complete(){
    var downloadURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;
    // this is the url i have to store in the Database

     var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('files');

    rootRef.push({
      url:downloadURL,
      name:contactName, //send contact name here.
      fullPath:(`files/${filetoUpload.name}`),
      created: `${new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]}`
       });



}
...
```

Comment: I am gettint that ContactName is not defined

Comment: btw, sorry for my battery problem before (0_0)7

Comment: What do you mean man ? IYoucould not even bother  thank you so much i am a begginer in javascript and i was totaly lost, thank you bro

Comment: feel free to send your WA or telegram to my email plonknimbuzz@gmail.com. but im playing dota right now. maybe tommorrow. because i think you need assistance of some friend

Answer (score 0):

Sending a second param to loadFile function. F.E:

```
loadFile(this, document.getElementById('ButtonId'))
```

or

```
loadFile(this, document.getElementById('ButtonId').value)
```

This second example sends the value, the first one sends the DOM object.

**Doing it dynamically:**

If you've more than one button add an onClick eventListener and add an id to them when onClick event occurs, then you can use the example dynamically.

```
<button class="buttonlistener" onClick="this.setAttribute('id', 'touched');" value"whatever">
```

back on the loadFile calls:

```
loadFile(this, document.getElementById('touched').value)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer man  but, how i will automatically know which button has been pressed?

Comment: I have edited the button line inside the table now the line looks lithis :    echo "<td>"."<button class=buttonlistener onClick=this.setAttribute(id,touched); value=".$record['Name']." id=contact>Upload File</button>"." </td>";    And also chankge the loadfile function as you ve shown abovr but nothing is happening

Comment: You must add the quotes as you do in plain HTML:
echo "<td><button class='buttonlistener' onClick='this.setAttribute(id,touched);' value='".$record['Name']."' id='contact'>Upload File</button></td>";
check well your code and debug if necessary...
Oh and,.. this is a JS question, not a php one.